# Linux fails to mount Android device in USB MSC mode

Tags: usb, linux, file-transfer

I wish to mount my Sony Xperia ST21i (Android 4.0.4) under Linux (Debian) via USB. However, I get this error:

```
# mount /dev/sdb /mnt
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb
```

What I did so far:

On the phone side: Settings > Xperia > Connectivity > USB connection mode: set to Mass storage mode (MSC), instead of the default Media transfer mode (MTP).

On the PC side: dmesg yields

```
[...] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 12
[...] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[...] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0fce, idProduct=e170
[...] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[...] usb 2-1.3: Product: Android
[...] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Android
[...] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: **********
[...] scsi14 : usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[...] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SONY     Mass storage     0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[...] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[...] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

For comparison, when mounting a cheap memory stick, dmesg yields

```
[...] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 13
[...] usb 2-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[...] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=1307, idProduct=0165
[...] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[...] usb 2-1.6: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
[...] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: P Technology
[...] usb 2-1.6: SerialNumber: 00000000000280
[...] scsi15 : usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0
[...] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     UT165    USB Flash Disk   0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] 3948544 512-byte logical blocks: (2.02 GB/1.88 GiB)
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[...]  sdb:
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[...] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Several lines more - is this significant? Does this mean, I need to configure my phone differently before I can hope to mount it?

Following advice in some related threads, I created an udev rule,

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
```

but this had no effect.

Comment: That rather looks like a Linux issue. Have you checked on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Mounting a USB memory stick is not a problem. When plugging the Android device, some pertinent lines are missing in the dmesg output. Therefore I tend to think of this as an Android issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered by @derobert at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90069/46841: MSC mode only works for accessing a memory card, which I do not have; for accessing the phone's own file system, I need another access mode.

Answer (score 1):

This commonly happens when you're trying to mount a disk when you should be mounting a partition on that disk. Use `ls /dev/sdb*` to see if any partitions (such as `/dev/sdb1`) exists on the disk, and then mount that instead of trying to mount the whole disk.

Comment: `ls /dev/sdb*` yields just `/dev/sdb`, so unfortunately this is not the solution

Comment: I agree with this answer. I had same problem. 'lsusb' showed phone. 'ls /dev/sdb*' showed sdb and sdb1. Phone is set to USB mass storage - also android debugging enabled. But it didn't mount automatically. Creating mount point 'sudo mkdir /media/sonyxperia' and mount 'sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/sonyxperia' worked.

Answer (score 1):

All I could think of on the Android side (enabling UMS) you've already done. But Android devices might not expose their full storage via UMS. Usually, you only can access the external *and internal* **SD-Cards** this way.

For everything else, you might want to take a look at [adbfs](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless) (see also [on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1816570)) and [mc-exfs-adb](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/23637-browse-phone-file-system-using-midnight-commander-linux-only/) (which I slightly modified to work better on my Linux system; that version you can find [here](http://stats.qumran.org/ftp/local/android/)). Both variants require you to have at least a minimal ADB installation on your computer (see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)).

I have tried both, and favor adbfs-rootless. Works like a charm. If your device is rooted, you could combine this with [adbd insecure](http://www.appbrain.com/app/%5Broot%5D-adbd-insecure/eu.chainfire.adbd) from Chainfire to get full access to the entire filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Joachim ...

To access the phone's internal storage you need to install libmtp and mtpfs for your linux distro. Something like :

sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /mnt

... should help.

Good discussion here : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1720464