# Mount /sdcard with Linux

Tags: sd-card, ssh, mtp

I have two Android 4.x devices, one 4.0.2 and another 4.4.2. On both, I have installed *SSHelper* to push data to and from the device using `rsync`. It worked, but the new environment does not even have a usable `rm`. I would like to switch over to something that works better and possibly faster.

My next attempt was to use MTP over USB with `mtpfs`, but that does not work, it freezes. `simple-mtpfs` is not packaged for Ubuntu 13.10. KDE *KIO* is able to read from the device over MTP, but that does not help me at all, since I want to write my own script using `rsync`, and it is not able to write to it.

Then I tried `sshfs`, I do not get any errors mounting it, but I get IO-errors whenever I even try to `cd` into the mountpoint. I guess the environment with *SSHelper* lacks something. It does not work with *HTTPS and FTPS Server* either. The SFTP provided with the latter works with *Filezilla*, though.

So how can I get `/sdcard` to be mounted somewhere on my Linux machine and copy and delete files from it like I want?

Comment: You might wish to try `adbfs` or `adb push`/`adb pull` (see my answers [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/53278/16575) and [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/56960/16575)). I use the former for quite a while now. Mounts like a normal "drive". Should be usable for `rsync`, though I didn't try. Of course, `adb push/pull` are not really suitable for "sync", but `adbfs` should be :)

Comment: `adbfs` does not sound bad. I guess that requires to install gigabytes of Android SDK? I just have tried to install a SFTP server on the 4.0.2 device. It works fine with Filezilla, but not with `sshfs`.

Comment: No, you don't need to install the entire Android SDK. You only need to `apt-get install android-tools-adb`. ADB itself is tiny and doesn't depend on the SDK. In turn, the only dependencies for `adbfs` are `adb` and `fuse`.

Comment: I tried `adbFS` and `adbfs-rootless`, both did not work. I wrote an email to both developers, let's see what comes around. By the way: I understand that “normal” people just use Google Drive or Dropbox and do not care about accessing the *real* file system, but is there no usable way to mount the `/sdcard`? From the Nexus 10, I cannot even get it out the device …

Comment: I can mount a few Android devices (including a Nexus 10) just fine from an Ubuntu 13.04 desktop via MTP. It worked out of the box. It might be easier asking our sister site [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) to help get MTP working on your desktop than trying to work around it on several Android devices.

Comment: How do you mount it exacly? Using `mtpfs`? Or do you use Nautilus or Dolphin?

Comment: @queueoverflow No full ADK needed, as dotVezz already noted: see [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575). As for `adbfs`, you might wish to take a look at [Tools for Android](http://www.izzysoft.de/ftp/local/android/) (my site), I did some corrections to make things work with Ubuntu 12.04. Guess that should do for 13.04/13.10 as well, but I didn't test. (PS: Ooops, I didn't put `adbfs` there for some reason? Need to check that... Ah! Watchout 4 `adbfs-rootless`, that's the working one. The other didn't work for me either)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to give `adbfs` a try, here are some instructions. You need to take care to grab the right one, as there are two projects around: one is simply called `adbfs`, I couldn't get that to work correctly. The other is `adbfs-rootless`:

1. go to [the projects github page](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless)
2. on that page, at the right-hand side in about the middle of the page, you find a button labeled [Download ZIP](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless/archive/master.zip). Click that to download the sources.
3. create a new directory, e.g. `mkdir ~/adbfs-rootless`, and extract the `.zip` to it
4. now first install the dependencies: `sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev`
5. change to the directory (`cd ~/adbfs-rootless`), and build the binaries by simply running `make`
6. copy the resulting `adbfs` binary into your `$PATH`, where your `adb` binary is located (for ADB, see [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575))

Now you're ready to go. Another one-time job is to create a mountpoint, e.g. `mkdir ~/droid`. After that, connect your Android device via ADB (after having enabled *USB debugging*, of course). Then mount it using `adb ~/droid`, and do whatever you wanted to do (e.g. running `rsync`, copying stuff, whatever). When you're done, don't forget to disconnect: `fusermount -u ~/droid`.

To make things easier, I created two aliases:

```
alias mdroid="adb ~/droid"
alias udroid="fusermount -u ~/droid"
```

So I only need to type `mdroid` to mount, and `udroid` to unmount the device.

Enjoy the fun!

Comment: I did all that, however `adb devices` does not list any devices. It does not work with either the *Nexus 10*, nor with the *Xperia Mini Pro*. They are recognized by `mtpfs`, but that fails for other reasons, apparently. I have not checked whether USB debugging is enabled, though.

Comment: OK, that's not the fault of `adbfs`. But I might have something helpful for that as well: please see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39437/16575) to get ADB running with Ubuntu and the Nexus :)

Comment: Once I enabled USB debugging, this kind works on the *Xperia Mini Pro* with Android 4.0.2. I have yet to find out how to enable USB debugging on the *Nexus 10* with Android 4.4.2. It does not really seem too stable, and `rsync` complains about a lot of missing functions in the file system.

Comment: I cannot help you with that, unfortunately: Neither I have a Nexus, nor Android 4.2+. I'm using that successfully with multiple devices running 2.3/4.0/4.1 (of course not simultaneously, but always only with one of them connected at a time).

Comment: So mu `rsync -avhE --delete --progress --whole-file --inplace` copies the files, complains about `chgrp` being not implemented, which is fine. However, it copies the files every time, which is dead slow. So far, it is not a viable replacement for rsync over SSH (if it was not broken). `-rvh` does not make it better, either.

Comment: @queueoverflow, Sorry if I'm asking an obvious question or giving obvious advice, but have you enabled the "Developer Options"  menu? (Go to "Settings"->"About Phone" and tap "Build number" 7 times). USB Debugging mode can be enabled from Developer Options.

Comment: @dotVezz probably yes, or it wouldn't work at all, as `adb` wouldn't even recognize the device :) queue: I do all my sync stuff using [FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/foldersync/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) via WiFi. Works like a charm. Sync events I trigger via [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). `adbfs` I mainly use for manual work (investigation, copying some files, etc.).

Comment: @Izzy, I was actually asking because he said `adb` does *not* recognize the device in his first comment and then said that he doesn't know how to enable Debugging on the Nexus 10 in his second comment. Or.. wait, am I missing something?

Comment: @dotVezz Yeah, the OP's last comment maybe? :) "[...] is dead slow [...] no viable replacement for rsync via SSH [...]" to me implies it's at least working ;)

Comment: @Izzy I'm so confused. Is he referring to `adb` in that comment? does `rsync` only work with debugging enabled or something? O_o As far as I can see, he hasn't said anything to indicate that he's got a working debugging mode... but I might just be crazy. Educate me!

Comment: @dotVezz He's used rsync via ssh before. I've recommended trying the same via adbfs. My answer doesn't mention mtpfs. So I don't see what else could be meant. (feel free (both of you) dropping into chat for details, before we "overload" the comments. Ya know I'm always there – though sometimes a little delayed, but I always "copy" :)