# When modifying files, I am getting permission denied

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I downloaded Android Bridge, and set my phone to debug mode. Using the console, I can enter the phone file system but when I try to modify files, it tells me "no permission."

How  can I bypass this without rooting my device?

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: I Dont thing so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell you get from `adb shell` doesn't run with special privileges, so you can't read or write files that you wouldn't be able to with a normal app. If you want to access apps' private data files, you still need to get root permission in the usual way, and use `su` from the shell.

It's not possible to bypass the permissions system. If you want to access inaccessible files, you need to root the device, then use a root app to access them.

Comment: Is it possible bind linux machine and reach files?

Comment: What do you mean by "bind"? You want to mount the file system on your Linux machine? That's possibe, as I've explained in [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/58783/16575). But it only gives you the very same permissions on those files as you have using `adb shell`.