# Unable to mount USB Storage of ECOO E04 Plus Android device in Ubuntu

Tags: usb-connection-mode

I have two phones. Ecoo E04 Plus and  MLAiS M52.

- Both running Kitkat 4.4.4.
- Both phones configured the same wrt USB connect mode (USB Storage).
- Both have USB debugging off.

When I connect the M52, a screen comes up with **USB connected** with a picture of a large Android holding a USB logo. It has a button **Turn on USB storage**. This all works.

Problem is, the ECOO won't popup this screen, and I can't figure out why.

- Changing USB debugging check box does not fix it.
- Changing USB storage to MTP does not fix it.
- `lsusb` with the M52 connected, I get:

  > Bus 001 Device 049: ID 0bb4:0001 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)
- With the ECOO connected, I get:

  > Bus 001 Device 050: ID 0bb4:0c03 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)
- `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` doesn't have anything on either.

Yet the M52 shows the screen letting me proceed by enabling the USB storage connection, but the ECOO stubbornly just sits there and couldn't be bothered to do a damn thing.

Searching the net for solution, the results were not useful in regard to MTP and PTP.

Comment: Until the question is sorted out, you may use the alternative here. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/is-there-a-viable-alternative-to-mtp-for-file-transfer/ There are three solutions, choose any of them, look specially by `Izzy`.

Comment: Yepp. And as you're on Linux, also take a look at [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/58783/16575) for some more comfort: You can even mount your storage to your Linux computer via ADB :) – As for your original question: Have you tried a) different cables, b) different USB ports, c) different computers, d) a mix of a-c? Does the problem exist in all combinations?

Comment: I'll probably end up doing the ADB thing. I've done it before when tinkering with a hello world app a while back. From what I gather, it might let me inject an su and busybox and effectively root the phone as well (as the "standard" tools like Framaroot don't appear to work).
-----
But what remains is, why does the ECOO only show the "Connected as USB Storage" notification, and does not show the additional "USB connected - Touch to copy files to /from your computer." notification?
-----
What is missing? Does the ECOO have this option turned off, and they want me to use specialized drivers?

Comment: New discoveries !
Booting from a Live Xubuntu 15.04 stick, *and* after doing an OTA update of the phone's firmware (not 5.0, still 4.4.4), mass storage still is not working.
However, when I set the phone's usb mode to MTP, then I noticed an icon appearing on the desktop labeled "G". I then opened the file manager and noticed there I could open it. It shows a directory called "Phone Storage". In that I'm finding the phone's content (or what is made available), including DCIM for pictures, etc.

Comment: I then booted my normal 13.10 Xubuntu partition again.
The icon on the desktop does not appear when plugging the phone in. However, and this didn't occur to me before, opening the file manager, it *does* show the G icon.
So the issues are, mass storage appears broken in the phone or USB is not handled right by Linux (which would not surprise me because USB has *always* been flaky on Linux - I have *never* seen it troublefree since '99 - there are *always* gotchas!).
Older Xubuntu's fail to pop up a desktop icon when they should, when connecting an MTP device.

Comment: Lastly, I am going to try connecting to it using adb.
I found this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2684210
which talks about manually rooting it. Framaroot and towelroot standalone utils didn't work. But that's another whole topic.
At least - one *can* connect to this particular phone using Linux, but there are gotchas (as always).

Comment: Any new updates Mike.

Comment: I screwed up my OS and had to reinstall it. I have no had the time to get further with it. What is really frustrating is that USB has been getting less reliable. My system would occasionally completely freeze after accidentally removing a USB drive before unmounting. But now with Xubuntu 15.04, I can not even mount my 4TB drive at all any more. It always completely freezes my system about 20 seconds after I plug it in. I have to hard reset to get out of it. I said that USB has always been unreliable on Ubuntu and I wasn't kidding. It's just that it has gotten much worse. Very embarrassing bugs