# Change the filesystem mounted when plugged in to USB

Tags: usb, file-system, mount

Is there a way to change the mount location when plugging a device into USB?

I want to move it to the root directory. I am rooted.

Please note that I want no setup done on the PC, that is, do not suggest methods involving changing the PC. If I have to, I will though.

Comment: MTP (the protocol used to make files available to your PC) is managed by Android itself. It does not feature a way to explore the root directory. You could however use ADB (Android Debugging Bridge) and use your command line to access the root of your device by using the command `adb shell` (given that either *adb* is inside the folder your command line is currently in or `adb` has been added to your PATH variable).

Comment: [Run a Web/FTP/WebDAV/SSH/Samba.. server on Android and access it on PC using hotspot or USB tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277). Otherwise, ADB is good. You may also consider [adbfs](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/58783/96277). Both methods would allow access using GUI.