# adbfs-rootless: "Transport endpoint is not connected"

Tags: usb, file-transfer

I was looking for a way to mount my phone in Linux, over USB, and I came across a recommendation to use [adbfs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58768/mount-sdcard-with-linux). I was able to download the files to a directory and run make, and I created a subdirectory called mnt.

When I run `./adbfs mnt` I get the output `--*-- exec_command: adb shell "ls"`.

When I try to navigate to the directory, I get `Transport endpoint is not connected`.

I know I am connected to the phone because when I run adb shell I can access the phone and navigate through its files.

Comment: Having found my recommendation in that answer, have you followed the link and checked the issues? You're probably running Android 7 or above, right? See: [Doesn't work on Nexus 5 after upgrade to Android 7.0: Transport endpoint is not connected](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless/issues/14) – it's a known issue and currently unsolved. That issue holds a "dirty work-around", though, if you're interested.