# How to find and access "device folder" using PC?

Tags: file-management

I have a rooted Android phone. I would like to access the `device` folder in order to find all these other folders: `acct`, `cache`, `config`, `d`, `data`, `dev`, `efs`, `ect`, `factory`.

Here's a picture in order to be more clear:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

However, when I connect the phone to the PC (running Ubuntu) using the USB cable the only thing that I find are the `Card` and `Phone` folders:

[image]

If I try to look for the folders listed previously, I cannot find anything!

I already know how to find and access them using apps like **ES File Explorer**, however, **my goal is to find and access those folders using my PC without using apps**! What should I do?

Comment: That "device folder" is actually the actually the root (`/`) directory (not root user's directory) of your system. Just like the `/` you see in your Ubuntu. You can't access them using MTP or UMS since they are controlled by Android and it doesn't have any provision to allow them to be seen. You may try the answer posted below by JustMe. Also see [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/53278/96277) by Izzy. If you happen to change your mind, and decides to use an app then see my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277).

Answer (score 1):

What You see is output of libmtp (Media transfer protocol) and appropriate plugins for file-manager. To access root directory of Android device from Linux, you might use

a) adb shell (using terminal - easy solution)
b) several mtp packages listed nicely [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP)

steps described in b) should allow You to mount root of Android device and access it from file manager, however it requires some non-trivial system modifications.